# How can I make bookmark print urls in the normal font?

Tags: fonts, bookmarks

## Situation

I am using the bookmark package to make links and e-mails in a letter clickable. I want the url and e-mail address to be displayed in the same font as the rest of the document.

## Question

What is the simplest (least verbose) way to achieve this? I could not find anything in the package documentation.

## Minimal example

```
\documentclass[fromemail=true,fromurl=true]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
    \setkomavar{fromname}{John Doe}
    \setkomavar{fromemail}[]{\href{mailto:john@example.com}{\nolinkurl{john@example.com}}}
    \setkomavar{fromurl}{\href{http://example.com}{\nolinkurl{example.com}}}
    \begin{letter}{
        Alice Alisson\\
        123 Alicestreet\\
        }
        
        \opening{Dear Alice,}
         please visit my website.
        \closing{Regards}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

## Rendered minimal example

[image]

I am not asking about the color, but the font!

Comment: This is *not* related to package `bookmark`, but to `hyperref`, that is loaded by package `bookmark`. Package `bookmark` only deals with PDF bookmarks, not with links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[fromemail=true,fromurl=true]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\urlstyle{same} %<----
\begin{document}
    \setkomavar{fromname}{John Doe}
    \setkomavar{fromemail}[]{\href{mailto:john@example.com}{\nolinkurl{john@example.com}}}
    \setkomavar{fromurl}{\href{http://example.com}{\nolinkurl{example.com}}}
    \begin{letter}{
        Alice Alisson\\
        123 Alicestreet\\
        }

        \opening{Dear Alice,}
         please visit my website.
        \closing{Regards}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]